# ST_Box2D in PostGIS 2.0

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I am getting an error trying to create a bounding box of a geometry using `ST_Box2D()`. Is the function deprecated? If so, what is the equivalent function?

```
SELECT ST_Box2D(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, its removed only available in legacy.sql.  Use Box2D instead of ST_Box2D.

The reason it was removed is that its a casting function so we standardized on having casting functions have same name as thing they cast to to be consistent with the rest of PostgreSQL proper.